# Where can I translate the Bergen beamer style?

Tags: beamer, titles, languages, naming

I would like to use the Bergen theme with orchid color scheme. It works well, but I have "Who?" and "Where?" on my title page - I would like to translate them to my language. How could I do this the easiest way (a quick and dirty solution is enough).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Bergen` theme uses the `innmargin` inner theme, and a search within `beamerinnerthemeinnmargin.sty` reveals that certain macros need to be redefined:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Bergen}

\def\insertauthorindicator{Wer?}% Default is "Who?"
\def\insertinstituteindicator{Von?}% Default is "From?"
\def\insertdateindicator{Wann?}% Default is "When?"

\begin{document}

\title{(Titel)}
\author{(Autor)}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]